# Horizontal Scrollbar in Google PDF Viewer

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have implement Google PDF viewer in my project with that given code and it gives me the Horizontal Scrollbar in IE7 & IE8 only. Please any one help me on this to remove the Horizontal Scrollbar.

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people might show their. You can read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Show what you've tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this css:

```
pdf {
     overflow-x: hidden;
}
```